# SQL - Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD'

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I'm having this issue with MySQL where it throws an error sometimes when trying to pull data from my database. Here's the text of this error in my logs:

```
2017-10-10 18:01:49.934 WARN 5 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2017-10-10 18:01:49.935 ERROR 5 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column 'start' at row 1
2017-10-10 18:01:49.969 ERROR 5 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: error executing work] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column 'start' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
```

From looking at other questions I know that this is a data corruption issue, but I'm not sure how to go about looking for the corrupt data (this is a massive database; a dump would be hundreds of thousands of lines and I have no idea where the corrupt data would be), let alone how to clean it out.

NOTE: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159118/incorrect-string-value-xef-xbf-xbd-for-column). That question only asks what's happening and nowhere in the answers to that question does it tell me one of the key things I'm asking for in mine... **which is how to find where the corrupt data is in my DB**.

Comment: I think that your answer is already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11162470/1597430

Comment: No.. looked at that one already. It says what the problem is but it doesn't say how I can go about finding where the corrupt data is, which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: Based on what you see in the logs are you fairly certain about the table to which the `start` column belongs? If so, what do you get from `SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME='start'` ...?